# Expected number of dice rolls of a $N$-sided die to get all the possible rolls

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

Consider a normal $6$-sided die, how many rolls do I need to do to get all the possible rolls from $1$ to $6$? In general, what's the expected number of rolls of an $N$-sided die to get all the possible rolls from $1$ to $N$?

Comment: Think about the expected number of rolls to go from needing to get $n+1$ more number to needing to get $n$ more numbers. Given that you haven't shown any attempt, I don't want to give you any more than this hint.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem